# How can I make the Win32 API window more modern looking?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, interface

I ordered Programming Windows Fifth Edition a few days ago, and started working with it.

I'm starting to learn the win32 api, however, I got a question. The windows do not look modern winxp/win vista/win 7 style at all. How do I fix this?

It currently looks like this, crap font and all.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Machiel

Comment: Are you completely new to programming? If so, I recommend you to take a look at this: http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/

Comment: @Camilo Martin: The visual designers in Visual Studio are for Managed projects only. They don't work for C and C++.

Comment: @Billy my point is that he should consider Visual Basic instead. Or Delphi if he likes the performance of C.

Comment: @Camilo Martin I am not totally new to programming. Just to the win32 api.

Comment: @Camilo: I would strongly advise against both Visual Basic and Delphi. VB because it encourages bad habits, and Delphi because it's poorly supported and obscure. C# would not be a bad choice though.

Comment: Win32 API in 2010? An interesting twist on masochism.

Comment: +1 for doing the hard yards with a classic tome, it is well worth it. You know that the author of that book now posts a lot of WPF and Silverlight related stuff on his blog now?

Comment: @Paul + @Slugster: There are some of us who can't require our users to download and install massive runtime libraries. I like managed languages, but the fact that you need to install the runtime first is a dealbreaker for many.

Comment: I love the Win32 API. Why abandon a perfectly working system, simply because it wasn't originally designed for teenagers who want to discuss today's outfit on social media?

Comment: Anyhow, what is the alternative? Should you do the next version of Photoshop, Microsoft Word, or GTA in HTML5+CSS+JS?

Comment: I love Win32 API, but in this days a framework that tells you to do "x,y,w,h"-ed your countrols, is not cool man.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the font right you should call this after `CreateWindow(Ex)`:

```
NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0);
HFONT hFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't, apparently, actually read the book. You're looking for [WM_SETFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632642(VS.85).aspx). There is a reason the common controls aren't the first thing the book covers.

Comment: I love getting random downvotes without so much as a freaking comment as to why. NOT!

Comment: I think the downvotes are because he's looking at more than fonts, he's looking for a more modern style overall. (Not knowing about the matter myself, I'm guessing there's a different widget-set and possibly an entirely different set of APIs, involved somehow.) Note that I did not leave a downvote.

Comment: @fennec: The images of the buttons he has posted are using the modern style (with the exception of the font). The classic buttons have grey borders, not blue.

Comment: I haven't searched long enough, I guess, in my enthusiasm, however, I am aware of WM_SETFONT, the problem is putting it to good use. I can't really find a snippet of code in the book that changes all the window's fonts to another font, to be honest.

Comment: @Machiel: There is no such built in function. Set the font for the given window before showing it. Yes, it's quite verbose, and a major pain in the neck. But that's what dealing with raw win32 is like. If you want the OS to handle most of this for you, you could consider using the "lazy" example in the dialogs section... can't remember the specific page number here, but Petzold implements the entire app in terms of a dialog instead of a window.

Comment: You're forgiven for not remembering the page number :)

Comment: +1 for realizing the fonts, not the button style, was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check `GetThemeSysFont` to fill a `LOGFONT` of an appropriate system font, create it using `CreateFontIndirect`, and `WM_SETFONT` to assign it to each control that you create.

To my knowledge there is no way to set a different default for newly created windows in your application.  Nor is there a way to set all of the windows that you've already created in a single step (ie. instead of just looping through them all, or assigning individually).  The exception is dialog boxes which when created from resources allow the resource to specify the font used for all of the controls on the dialog box.

Comment: No, you don't want to use DEFAULT_GUI_FONT, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/07/436435.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the font for each control with [WM_SETFONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-setfont), you create the font by passing [NONCLIENTMETRICS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-nonclientmetricsa).lfMessageFont to [CreateFontIndirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontindirecta) (Use [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa)(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, ...) to get NONCLIENTMETRICS)

For [dialog boxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxa), you use the pseudo font "[MS Shell Dlg](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050204-00/?p=36523)" @ 8pt on < Vista and "Segoe UI" @ 9pt on >= Vista

Answer (score 1):

You might want to post some screen shots of exactly what differences you are talking about, this would help in figuring out what you need to change.

In general I would say that you probably need to include an approprite manifest with your app so your app uses the latest common controls.

Also, these days most UI is not developed using SDK style code, this is very difficult to program/maintain, instead use some kind of UI library, MFC at the very least.