# SendMessage and ncm not changing font

Tags: c++, winapi

I have looked for answers and I have found some that didn't work, so I would be grateful if anybody can help with this.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323541/how-can-i-make-the-win32-api-window-more-modern-looking) I used the `NONCLIENTMETRICS` typedef and the `SendMessage` function to find and create a font.

I have ran it before everything in the `WM_CREATE` switch, though the post said to run it before the window is created, and I'm pretty sure `WM_CREATE` is run **after** the window is created but I tried it anyway.

Code of the `setfont()` function:

```cpp
void setfont(HWND hWnd) {
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0);
    HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
}
```

Please tell me if I need to show any other code.

I have tried the `CreateFont` way, but that didn't work as well, so I'm hoping someone can tell me where I went skewer.

Note I'm using Visual Studio 2022

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of window is `hWnd`? Is that a window from your own class? Then your class needs to handle the `WM_SETFONT` message and remember that font for its future rendering.

Comment: `hWnd` is from my only class as you said. And how would I remember the font?

Comment: @TheException Use a variable, either global or per-instance if you have an object/window relationship. But note that you can bypass `WM_SETFONT` altogether and just create and save the font handle for use when rendering.

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried to use `SendMessage` in `WM_SETFONT` but the font doesn't change.

Comment: There is no system default implementation for the `WM_SETFONT` message. You are responsible for implementing it yourself in a manner you see fit. This is like texting yourself a message that says "Wash the dishes", and then wondering why the dishes are dirty. You are just talking to yourself. In this case, your code needs to remember the font so it can use it to draw text in its paint handler.

Comment: How do I go about remembeing the font?

Comment: The same way you remember anything else. In a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614572/appendmenu-font-change-c)

Steps:

- Make the font, Via `CreateFont` or `CreateFontIndirect`
- Add a `HWND` to the button or static control your trying to make
- Last of all, use this line to set the font:

`SendMessage([HWND of the control], WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)[Font HFONT], TRUE);`